# md-input-container NOT working as expected

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2, typescript2.1

I have the simple markup using "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1"

```
import {
  MaterialModule, MdIconRegistry, OVERLAY_PROVIDERS, MdInputContainer,
  MdInputDirective
} from '@angular/material'

....

<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput>
</md-input-container>
```

When I try to run the code I am getting

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./RaceComponent class RaceComponent - inline template:19:4 caused by: md-input-container must contain an md-input directive. Did you forget to add md-input to the native input or textarea element?
```

MdInput is directive is marked as deprecated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<md-input-container>
  <input md-input>
</md-input-container>
```

instead of

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput>
</md-input-container>
```

i had the same issue yesterday. Something has changed, but the documentation has not updated yet.

Comment: Thanks for this. Solved it for me, too. Docs clearly say they've deprecated md-input in favor of mdInput. But it ain't working that way with the latest distro. Maybe somebody reverted a commit?